# Determine a value if conditions between certain rows and columns are met in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, nested-loops

For a project I need to preproccess data from a hospital and eventually make a predictive model.

In one of my preproccessing steps, I need to make a column that represents the number of cumulative days a patient was in the hospital. This number is determined by looking at several other columns in different rows. Also, a patient can be hospitalized multiple times on different occasions. I'm sorry if this is very confusing.

I've added a picture of a dataframe. I want to know how I can make an argument with R to make the column cdays out of the column Patientid and Date.
[sample of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQBee.png)

I've tried numerous ways to do this. Some were using `for` and `while` loops with counters. And others were using a nested `ifelse` with new vectors (so I could compare current rows with rows of a iteration before):

```
#i-1 en i c.days
df$c.days <- 0
df$i_min_1c.days <- 0

#i en i+1 date
iDate<-df$Date[1:(nrow(df)-1)]
i_plus_1Date<-df$Date[2:(nrow(df))]

#i en i+1 patientid
iPatientid<-df$Patientid[1:(nrow(df)-1)]
i_plus_1Patientid<-df$Patientid[2:(nrow(df))]

newNew<-c(ifelse(iPatientid==i_plus_1Patientid, ifelse(i_plus_1Date-iDate>1,1,df$i_min_1c.days + 1), 1), df$c.days[nrow(df)])
```

Obviously this didn't work, but I was hopeless.... Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to proceed?

Some notes:
- The complete dataframe is 800k rows long and it's 9 columns wide (keep in mind conversions will take a lot of time)
- The value of cdays starts at 1 since it will be used as a multiplier,
- If the date difference between the ith and i+1th is bigger than 1 day, it will be considered as a new session and the cdays value would be 1.

If you need any more information, feel free to ask. I will try my best! Thank you very much and I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: 'This number is determined by looking at several other columns' - please provide them.

Comment: I suggest you read a little bit about providing a good question: [SO q/a on reproducibliity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), [SO's help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [SO's how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Bottom line: if you cannot execute the code in this question in a fresh/empty R session, then neither can anyone else, often making it very difficult to provide relevant advice or answers.

Comment: (Saying the same thing as r2e a different way) We do not need to see your actual data. Instead you should work on making a minimal reproducible example for us to look at that covers the issue you're facing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Comment: *to make the column cdays out of the column Patientid and Date* ... but your sample screenshot has such a column, *cdays*. What is your objective?

Comment: I want to know how to make such a column with R code. I ve made a sample with the result I am seeking.

Comment: @anotherfred in the sample the column "cdays" is the number I want as a result. It's just a counter that counts how many consecutive days a unique patient has been in a hospital with the condition that the difference between the dates arent longer than 1.

Comment: Hussain, please do not expect people to transcribe from an image of data; it is just as easy to paste the output of `dput(head(x,18))` as it is to take a screenshot and upload to SO/imgur. And because it makes it much easier for potential answerers to test with *your* data, it makes it much more likely that you can get a *prompt* and *relevant* answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a large dataset, use `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) #convert to data table
setorder(df, Patientid, Date) #am assuming your dates are R dates and not characters
df[, cdays := ifelse(
    Date == shift(Date) + 1,
    shift(cdays) + 1,
    1
),
by=Patientid]
```

The question is vague enough that I may easily have misunderstood it.